# logging updating all files with all ouput when using thread

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

I have a code

```
def config_logger(name,mainlog):
    #testlog="/home/oratest/test1/logs/test.log"
    logger = logging.getLogger(name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s : %(funcName)s : %(levelname)s --> %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S%p')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(mainlog,'w')
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)    
    return(logger)
threads=[]
`for db in dbargs["dbnames"]:
    thread=threading.Thread(target = fdbv.validations, args = (dbargs,db,))            
    thread.start()
    threads.append(thread)        
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
stopthreads=[]        
for db in dbargs["dbnames"]:
    stopthread=threading.Thread(target = fdbv.dbstop, args = (dbargs,db,))            
    stopthread.start()
    stopthreads.append(stopthread)        
for stopthread in stopthreads:
    stopthread.join()
```

validations and dbstop has their own logfiles in the function.

When I run this code. I see dbstop function O/P also being written to validations logfile.

validations logfile should be updated with dbstop function O/P.
Please let me know a solution

When I run this code. I see dbstop function O/P also being written to validations logfile.

validations logfile should be updated with dbstop function O/P.
Please let me know a solution

Comment: You're not showing how you're calling `config_logger`. In any case, `getLogger(name)` will always return the same instance of a logger; if you call `config_logger` multiple times with the same `name`, the logger will be configured multiple times.

Comment: def validations(dbargs,db):

    if dbargs["mode"] == "START":
        dbvalidationslog=dbargs["SCR_LOG"]+"/"+platform.node().split('.')[0]+"_"+db+"_postvalidations_"+dbargs["runtime"]+".log"
    elif dbargs["mode"] == "STOP":
        dbvalidationslog=dbargs["SCR_LOG"]+"/"+platform.node().split('.')[0]+"_"+db+"_prevalidations_"+dbargs["runtime"]+".log"
    logger=flog.config_logger(db,dbvalidationslog)


def dbstop(dbargs,db):

    dbstoplog=dbargs["SCR_LOG"]+"/"+platform.node().split('.')[0]+"_"+db+"_stop_"+dbargs["runtime"]+".log"
    logger=flog.config_logger(db,dbstoplog)

Comment: Don't add comments to clarify; code is unreadable in comments. [Edit] your question instead.